# Работа с git в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Существуют ли какие-либо инструменты в `Android Studio` для мерджа без боли? Чтобы при конфликте мерджа была подсветка приходящих и текущих изменений и можно было просто выбрать что оставить, а что убрать, как это сделано в `Visual Studio Code`

Comment: Да, они туда встроены. Всё красиво и прикольно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio сделана на "движке" от IntelliJ, и как и в IDEA, в ней удобно работать с системами контроля версий.

Вот гайд для IntelliJ IDEA, но он почти полностью (если не полностью) подойдёт и для Android Studio: [ссылка на гайд](https://javadevblog.com/nastrojka-git-v-intellij-idea.html).